Epson cartridges stuck to the far left side
I have a printer EPSON XP-235 using it with a Kubuntu.
The printer cartridges are stuck in the far left side. I have restarted the printer, unplugged it and pressed all buttons but the cartridges don't return to the start right position.
What can I do to fix this?

you can read the user manual

Adapted from ifixit.com:

Hold the stop button six seconds -- the head should move.

Release the stop button, then press it once. The print head may move a bit to the left.

Press it once again, and it should move to the far left; you may have to press it multiple times to get the head parked.
Alternatively, from YouTube:

Turn the printer off.

Turn the printer on, and while the print head is traversing, unplug the power cord when the print head and cartridges are in an accessible position.


If neither work, then likely there is a mechanical issue with the printer, such as an unplugged or broken cable, which requires repair.
